# How to get all checked checkboxes value by ng-model in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yoaqmobt/).
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in list">
            <div mycb group="{{item.group}}" title="{{item.title}}" is-checked="item.isChecked" value="{{item.value}}" update="callMe()"></div>
        </div>
        <p>{{result}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.list = [
        { group: "pet", title: "dog", isChecked: true, value: "dog" },
        { group: "pet", title: "cat", isChecked: true, value: "cat" },
        { group: "pet", title: "bird", isChecked: true, value: "bird" },
        { group: "pet", title: "snake", isChecked: true, value: "snake" },
        { group: "pet", title: "boy", isChecked: true, value: "boy" },
        { group: "pet", title: "cup", isChecked: true, value: "cup" }
    ];
    $scope.callMe = function(){
        var collection = [];
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.list.length;i++){
            var isChecked = $scope.list[i].isChecked;
            if(isChecked){
                collection.push($scope.list[i].value);
            }
        }
        $scope.result = collection.join(" ");
    }
}])
.directive("mycb", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            title: "@",
            isChecked: "=",
            group: "@",
            value: "@",
            update: "&"
        },
        template: "<input type='checkbox' ng-model='isChecked' name='{{group}}' value='value' ng-change='update()'>{{title}}"
    };
})
```

I created a group of checkbox and it will be updated when each of them is clicked.
By default, all checkboxes are checked. When I click the first one, it will be turned to status unchecked. The value of other checked boxes will show up.

#### For example:

dog,cat,bird,snake,boy,cup
When I click dog, the checkbox of dog will be turned to unchecked and "cat,bird,snake,boy,cup" will show up. Actually, it not happened like that. It shows "dog,cat,bird,snake,boy,cup".
Please check it out and give me a hand. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an arrray to keep track of the boxes that are checked.

```
       $scope.selectedCheckboxes = [];
       $scope.callMe=function(item){
          var idx = $scope.selectedCheckboxes.indexOf(item);

          // is currently selected
          if (idx > -1) {
                 $scope.selectedCheckboxes.splice(idx, 1);
          }

          // is newly selected
          else {
                 $scope.selectedCheckboxes.push(item);
          }
   };
```

And in html pass item.value to callMe function. You wil have all the value that are checked in $scope.selectedCheckboxes

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in list">
          <div mycb group="{{item.group}}" title="{{item.title}}" is-checked="item.isChecked" value="{{item.value}}" update="callMe(item.value)"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
   <div mycb group="{{item.group}}" title="{{item.title}}" is-checked="item.isChecked" value="{{item.value}}" ng-change="callMe()"></div>
</div>
```

Use ng-change event. Call Me function called when the user clicked on the checkbox. you can easily track all the checked checkbox in the controller.

Let me know if you need help more. Thanks.